# Python script - update file path in image texture node

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I have produced a script to run through an input folder of images, update the file path of each image inside the "Painting" image texture node, and produce a rendered image of each iteration. However, it causes Blender to crash. I am trying to print some errors to the console but it crashes each time.

Can anyone advise on why?

````
import bpy
import os

# Set the folder containing the painting images
folder_path = "/path/to/your/folder"

# Set the output directory for rendered images
output_directory = "/path/to/your/output/folder"

# Get the active scene and render settings
scene = bpy.context.scene
render_settings = scene.render

# Set the resolution and file format
output_format = render_settings.image_settings.file_format
resolution_x = render_settings.resolution_x
resolution_y = render_settings.resolution_y

# Get the painting material
painting_material = bpy.data.materials.get("Acrylic / Metal")

# Check if the painting material exists
if painting_material is None:
    print("Error: The painting material 'Acrylic / Metal' does not exist.")
    exit()

# Get the image texture node in the material
image_texture_node = painting_material.node_tree.nodes.get("Painting")

# Check if the image texture node exists
if image_texture_node is None:
    print("Error: The image texture node 'Painting' does not exist in the material.")
    exit()

# Iterate over each file in the folder
for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if file_name.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')):
        # Set the image file for the painting
        image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
        print(f"Loading image: {image_path}")
        image_texture_node.image.filepath = image_path

        # Set the output file path for the rendered image
        output_file = os.path.join(output_directory, os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] + '.' + output_format.lower())

        # Set the render output properties
        render_settings.filepath = output_file

        print(f"Rendering image: {output_file}")

        # Render the image
        try:
            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
            print(f"Rendered image: {output_file}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error rendering image: {output_file}")
            print(f"Error message: {str(e)}")

        # Check for 'escape' key press
        if bpy.ops.wm.check_cancel():
            print("Rendering canceled.")
            break

print("Rendering complete!")
```
````

Comment: try `image_texture_node.image.filepath_raw = image_path`